# Spring security userdetails: org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

i try to perform a login process with spring-boot, oauth2 and spring security. I implemented a custom userdetails service.

Here the code:

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s does not exist!", username));
         return new UserRepositoryUserDetails(user);
    }

    private final static class UserRepositoryUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private UserRepositoryUserDetails(User user) {
            super(user);
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            return getRoles();
        }

        // another methods

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() { return super.isEnabled(); }
    }
}
```

The user entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(50)")
    private String userUUId;

    // another parametes
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT DEFAULT false")
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
    private boolean enabled;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(User user) {
        super();
        this.userUUId = user.getUserUUId();
        this.roles = user.getRoles();
        this.name = user.getName();
        this.email = user.getEmail();
        this.enabled = isEnabled();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
    }
    // ...
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

The security configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

And a part of an authorizationserver configuration:

```
@Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    @Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean(name = "tokenStore")
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new InMemoryTokenStore();
        }

        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        }
```

Here the error log:

```
    type=AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException, message=User is disabled}]
    [2016-08-25 09:23:17.774] boot - 21158  INFO [http-nio-8443-exec-1] --- TokenEndpoint: Handling error: InvalidGrantException, User is disabled
[2016-08-25 09:23:17.832] boot - 21158 DEBUG [http-nio-8443-exec-1] --- OrderedRequestContextFilter: Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@6ea0e0af
[2016-08-25 09:23:17.837] boot - 21158 ERROR [http-nio-8443-exec-4] --- EndpointsAuthentification: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
[2016-08-25 09:23:17.839] boot - 21158 DEBUG [http-nio-8443-exec-4] --- OrderedRequestContextFilter: Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4afe7f7
[2016-08-25 09:23:17.840] boot - 21158 ERROR [http-nio-8443-exec-4] --- [dispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.x.server.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:76)
```

But i am sure, the user account is enabled. A call of user.isEnabled return true, but the framework cannot detect it.

Any ideas?
Cheers

Comment: Can you post the User code?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the **enabled** field in database is **null** or **false**

Answer (score 1):

The `org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException` is thrown when the `isEnabled()` method of the `UserDetails` returns `false`.

From your implementation, `User user = userService.findByUsername(username);` in the `CustomUserDetailsService` is fetching from database a user whose `enabled` property is `false`.
Find a way to change it to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

in your `UserDetailsImpl` class, `isEnabled` must be return true;

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```